# The names and avatars of the chat bots

Tags: discussion, chat

We currently have two chat bots posting feed into the chat room, [The Awkward Silence](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61165/the-awkward-silence).

#### Main

There's [Extroverted Main Man](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-677/extroverted-main-man) - all the new questions to the main site are posted with this user profile. This is the avatar.

[image: the avatar of Extroverted Main Man, a man in a business suit with his arms spread out]

#### Meta

There's [Introverted Meta Man](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-664/introverted-meta-man) - all new meta questions are posted with this user profile. This is the avatar.

[image: the avatar of Introverted Meta Man, a man in a business suit with his hands in his pockets]

What do people want as the chat bot profiles?

Comment: Personally I don't like the default setting on gender being male - it's about time it changed. Not here - everywhere

Comment: Well, why do we assume bots need gender anyway?

Comment: @NVZ exactly! My point exactly - I know I'm a fierce equal rights fighter.. and people probably get sick of me bringing it up.

Comment: Thing is, humans are designed to see faces where there are none, and similarly, genders where there are none (aka Pareidolia). Plus, unless some extra 'feminine' features are given, humans mostly assume robots are males.

Comment: @NVZ humans don't mostly assume robots are male. You'd need to cite evidence of that - that's a huge discussion. There's plenty of avatars that are unisex - images of animals, cartoons, inanimate objects

Comment: I don't think a chat bot should be posting questions from the main site at all. It's just noise. Meta is more useful because it's rarer, and more important to have exposure.

Comment: @curiousdannii that's a separate issue. If you would like to bring it up on meta, please do! I personally prefer the bot as that's how most of the sites I use have their chat rooms set up but I'd be happy to see your arguments for the other side.

Comment: "Introverted Meta Man." has a dot at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Adjust them to the gender-neutral names **The Extrovert** and **The Introvert**.

I like the idea of having a contrasting pair of names, but I was bothered by the gender imbalance as well. But *extrovert* and *introvert* can be both adjective and noun, so there's no need to use them as adjectives.

Also, let's drop the "main" and "meta"; it is clear enough where a question is coming from.

Comment: Just a bit boring :/

Answer (score 0):

## Keep it!

The *Extroverted Main Man* and the *Introverted Meta Man* are perfect because they are relevant names for bots to the site's topic: Interpersonal Skills.

If there truly is a serious gender imbalance issue, then we can just change the names (and avatars consequently) to something like "Extroverted Main Woman" or to something more pronoun-neutral such as "Extroverted Main Human/Alien/Being" or so forth.

I mean, certainly they are much better than a plain "Question Mark."

Comment: being introverted and extroverted are good ideas and relevant - but there's many other terms that are relevant and they can be linked to other nouns - we don't need to mention the word "main" at all - meta's probably a good idea. I went through a bunch of chat rooms to see what others had.

Answer (score -2):

Mix up Main/Meta x Man/Woman.

## Main Man, Met A Woman, and lived happily ever after.

Answer (score -3):

If the problem is gender imbalance, then maybe you can change the profiles to "Extroverted Main Woman" and "Introverted Meta Woman". Or you can use "Extroverted Main Mammal" or something similar if you don't want any reference to gender at all. Which would keep the symmetry and fix the gender imbalance.

Comment: It loses the alliteration, which is what makes them catchy. Also I don't like the introduction of gender to tell you the truth.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Introverted Main Mammoth? Introverted Main Mammal? Introverted Main Muffin?

Comment: I thought of animal names, but wasn't sure if the community would want animals - that's why when I made the unilateral change - I used a question mark. It doesn't have to include introverted or extroverted. We have an open slate and can use anything.